# Word for eyeglasses with no prescription

Tags: single-word-requests

I once heard/read a word for eyeglasses that have no presciption in the lenses. Just plan glass, worn for effect. Can someone recall that word for me?

Comment: I've been wearing such glasses for well over twenty years now, and I wouldn't know that there's a word for them. (Well, there is in German, but that's because German has a word for everything.) Hope someone else can help you out.

Comment: Reading glasses?  Fashion glasses?

Comment: It likely depends on the reason they exist?  Are they a fashion statement? A safety precaution?  A part of a costume?

Comment: I'm with @Jim. That's one reason why it's important to include a sample sentence, as [the SWR tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) says!

Comment: Many drug stores sell reading glasses that correct for hyperopia/presbyopia with a condensing lens (thicker in the center than at the edges, like a magnifying glass). These do not involve or require any prescription from an optometrist, but they do supply a correction. So if you are looking for a term specifically denoting optically *neutral* spectacles, non-prescription isn't really the defining criterion you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The term used by optometrists, opticians, and similar professionals for the 'lenses' that perform no refractive function is *plano* (in Latin, *planus* means flat). The term is, however, unlikely to be readily understood by the general public.

Answer (score 4):

The common term for this is simply **non-prescription glasses**.

From ["The Benefits of Non-Prescription Glasses"](https://www.classicspecs.com/about/articles/71-default) by Priya Modi at Classic Specs:

> Many of us can recall our memorable days of being made fun of in elementary school for wearing glasses. (Does “four-eyes” ring a bell?) Luckily for you, things have changed since then, and we are onto a new chapter in our lives where we now have a positive relationship with the glasses we wear every day. Nowadays, glasses give wearers a bold look that creates a fashion statement which enhances your overall appearance, rather than taking away from it. Different styles and frames can complement your outfit whether you’re running errands or at the office in heels. Sometimes, we all need a break from wearing contact lenses in our eyes so the naked eye can have more oxygen. However, people, regardless of their vision, are starting to wear them just because it looks good. These are called non-prescription glasses and there are more benefits than just fashion or a simple desire to wear. Below are some benefits of non-prescription glasses.

From Wikipedia's [entry on glasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasses):

> Much like other fashion designs and accessories, eyewear is created by designers, has reputable labels, and comes in collections, by season and designer. It is becoming more common for consumers to purchase eyewear with clear, non-prescription lenses, illustrating that glasses are no longer a social stigma, but a fashionable accessory that "frames your face."

---

Even more colloquially, people will refer to them as *fake glasses* or *clear glasses*.

From [Cosmic Eyewear](https://www.cosmiceyewear.com/collections/clear-glasses-277-aspx):

> Here you'll find one of the largest, budget friendly & best selections of clear non-prescription (glasses without prescription) optical quality designer fake reading eye glasses to match your personality, fashion or style statement! Shop affordable accessories & hundreds of clear glasses for men & women.

And people in theatre or film might even refer to them as *prop glasses*, especially if they are only frames without lenses at all. (However, *prop* is a generic attributive noun for any number of items and accessories.)

Comment: This is often an adequate term for such glasses, but in the absence of disambiguating context it could be taken to stand for something different: the reading glasses that the health regulations of the relevant country permit to be sold without a prescription.